# IE 8 not losing Bootstrap container effect

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-8

When I started making this web app in PHP I thought I would easily accomplish the project by giving the Bootstrap container effect , but gradually with the development I realized that I need more content on the page because of scope change and I no more want Bootstrap container effect and want to use the full page for my web app(with side panels and shortcuts etc.)

Now the problem what I am facing is that IE 8 is not losing that container effect even when I remove the tags. Currently I replaced the tags with col.md 10 for main content on one side and col.md 2 for sidebar.

The change has been beautifully adapted by Chrome ,Firefox and safari.I researched a lot but I cannot find the solution to this problem.I am a beginner in bootstrap and PHP.

Below are the header files and main tags.

```
<head>    
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->       
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <!-- Meta to make IE compatible with Font awesome -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,IE=8,9,10">

    <!-- File inclusion of JS and CSS -->
    <?php
    include ('config/css.php');
    include ('config/js.php');
    ?>
</head>
```

**Body**
`

```
<div class="col-md-2 " id="sidebar">
    <div class="navbar-header"><h4>Generate Reports</h4> </div>
     <div class = "navbar-collapse collapse"></div>
     <ul class="nav navbar-default" id="sidebar">
          <li><a href="#S1"><i class="fa fa-chain-broken "></i>&nbsp; Sidebar button 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#S2"><i class="fa fa-scissors "></i>&nbsp; Sidebar button 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#S3"><i class="fa fa-link "></i>&nbsp; Sidebar button 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#S4"><i class="fa fa-magic "></i>&nbsp; Sidebar button 4</a></li>
     </ul>   
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 pull-right">
    <h4>Wire List</h4>
    <div class="main_data" >
        <?php
        include ('template/displaycontent.php');
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

I am struggling with this issue for few days now and the thing is company default browser is IE8 and thus it has to be compatible with it.  I would appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: If you want the container to be 100% of the page width, just use `container-fluid` instead of `container`, rather than removing the containers altogether.

Comment: @cvrebert - Still the IE 8 layout is not loosing the effect.